# Why there is no spring project in new->file->spring but only have some other kinds of spring project such as Legacy,Roo,Starter

Tags: spring, spring-tool-suite

After I finished to add the STS to eclipse,when I just want to build a new spring project ,but there is no [spring project] under the [Spring] menu,but only:

1. import spring Getting started content
2. Spring Legacy Project
3. Spring Roo Project
4. Spring starter Project

Answer (score 0):

The best way to create a new empty Spring project is to use the "Spring Starter Project" wizard. It creates a new Spring Boot project and allows you to select the boot starters that you want to use to populate the classpath of your project with the necessary libraries. Under the hood it uses http://start.spring.io.

If you would like to get started with Spring and would like to follow one of the guides from http://spring.io/guides, the "Import Getting Started Content" wizard is the best choice. It offers you to download those guides directly into your workspace and work with them.

The "Spring Legacy Project" wizard is an outdated one that allows you to create plain Spring projects that use older Spring versions. This will soon be gone in future versions.

The "Spring Roo Project" wizard uses Spring Roo under the hood, a specific technology to work with Spring projects. This is definitely not the right wizard for you if you just want to create a new Spring project (without dealing with Spring Roo in the future).

Hope this helps!